# Storing outputs from nested for loop in arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

```
        for x in range (1, 10)
           for y in range (1,10)
             for z in range (1,10)
             #In this loop, I perform some operations to generate an
             #output that has a shape (500,4). By using this output, I perform 
             #another set of operations as shown below)
              for i in range(1,500)
                 if i == 20
                    p = somevalue_1 #(which is derived by using columns in outpout(500,4)
                 if i == 40
                    q = somevalue_2 #(which is derived by using columns in outpout(500,4)
                 if i == 60
                    r = somevalue_3 #(which is derived by using columns in outpout(500,4)
                 if i == 80
                    s = somevalue_4 #(which is derived by using columns in outpout(500,4)
```

So, for 1000 iterations (10x10x10), I want to collect the values p,q,r,s (shape(1000,4)).

Comment: in your last `for loop` you are checking condition upto 80 only, then why do you wants to iterate up to 500 `for i in range(1,500)`?

Comment: It was an example. depending upon the type of output I need, I change those values.

Comment: Note that, `range (1,10)` loops for 9 iteration, not 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a list of list and range (1, 11) for getting 10 values:

```
allData = []
for x in range (1, 11):

    for y in range (1,11):

        for z in range (1,11):
            p=q=r=s = ''
            for i in range(1,500):

                if i == 20:
                    p = somevalue_1 #(which is derived by using columns in outpout(500,4)
                if i == 40:
                    q = somevalue_2 #(which is derived by using columns in outpout(500,4)
                if i == 60:
                    r = somevalue_3 #(which is derived by using columns in outpout(500,4)
                if i == 80:
                    s = somevalue_4 #(which is derived by using columns in outpout(500,4)
            temp =[p,q,r,s]
            allData.append(temp)
```

here allData list contains the full data with shape 1000,4

Comment: I tried to implement this method but I get an error which says 'NameError: name 'p' is not defined.

Comment: So, you need to define p,q,r,s previously. I have editted my answer

Comment: there was some indentation issues and you need range 1 to 11 for making 1000 values..check the updated code